# Returning a seesaw to balanced

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, torque

Suppose I have a seesaw that is tilted to the left because a force of 10N is being applied to it. While the seesaw is still tilted to the left, I apply a force of 10N to the right side of the seesaw (the same distance away from the fulcrum as the left-side force is). Will the seesaw return to a balanced state, or will it remain tilted to the left? Both forces are being applied perpendicular to the seesaw surface.

Comment: Is the pivot frictionless?

Comment: It is frictionless. Sorry, I forgot to mention that

Comment: Is there some sort of limit the seesaw can tilt to?: If not it will continue to rotate until the LHS is at the lowest point...

Comment: Sorry, I should've mentioned that too. There is a limit. There's a floor that prevents the seesaw from becoming vertical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the seesaw is tilted to the left, but not moving.

Given a frictionless pivot, if the seesaw is tilted to the left but not moving, then there must be another 10 N force on the right so that the sum of the moments about the pivot is zero. As such, the seesaw is already in balance, albeit not necessarily level (horizontal).

It is similar to the situation in which two equal masses are connected by a massless string over a frictionless pulley. You can manually move them so that that they are at different levels and they will not move after gently releasing them while still. They are still in balance.

In your case, if you add a force to the right the seesaw will be out of balance.

> Thanks very much. this does help. So to get it back in balance I would
>   need to apply a force greater than 10N to the right side, and
>   gradually decrease that force to 10N as it approaches the
>   balanced/horizontal state, right?

If you mean by "back in balance" you mean making the seesaw horizontal, then yes you can do it that way.  But it really doesn't matter how much additional force you apply or how gradually you apply it. Because all you need to do is move it to a horizontal position (or any new position, for that matter). Then, with the seesaw not having any motion in that position, gently release it in the horizontal position.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks very much. this does help. So to get it back in balance I would need to apply a force greater than 10N to the right side, and gradually decrease that force to 10N as it approaches the balanced/horizontal state, right?

Comment: @physicsboi123123  I incorporated your follow up question, and the answer to it, in a revision to my answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: This helped a lot. Thank you!